# Port Python v2 function to v3

Tags: python

This v2 function gives a "NameError: global name 'file' is not defined" error when run in v3.

```
def from_file(filename, sep='\n'):  
    "Parse a file into a list of strings, separated by sep."  
    return file(filename).read().strip().split(sep)
```

Could someone please provide a v3 version?

Comment: Should be `with open(filename) as f: return f.read().strip().split()` so the file is closed properly. Also, you might want to consider whether this is necessary or if the standard line-based iteration (which uses vastly less memory) is enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 7):

Change the `file` call to `open`.